# Getting gamecenter friend's thumbnail url

Tags: facebook, url, game-center

I am able to get the thumbnails of my facebook friends from their fbid using the URL `http://graph.facebook.com/<fbid>/picture?type=square`

Is there a similar way to do it for Gamecenter?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `GKPlayer`'s `loadPhotoForSize:withCompletionHandler:` method once you have their GKPlayer object.  See Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKPlayer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) for more details.

Comment: This returns the photo itself but I want the URL, which can be accessed not only from iOS devices.